# How to handle accessing data from belongsTo relationship when the 'parent' is deleted in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I have a database with users and a database with posts. A user has many posts. When a user deletes their account, I don't want to have their posts deleted. This results in a problem: when I try to access name of the post author (like this: `$post->user->name` ), I get an error `Attempt to read property "name" on null`. What I would like to get is something like "Deleted user". How can I achieve this?

Comment: Don't delete user accouts. **Mark** them deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can depend on the relation from the eloquent only.

but Do not use foreign key To avoid sql problems

Here are the solutions ...

You can delete the author admin using the soft delete

You can Show modal before deletion Confirms that this author has many active articles

You can transfer articles from one author to another. When the deletion command is executed, the alternative is specified by default in the method
Or it is determined from the confofim modal

You can make an accessor method in model
check if isset author relation if null return The alternative that matches your idea

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think I will use the soft deletion. If nobody comes with a better idea in next few days, I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is fixed :

```
$post->user==null ? 'Deleted User': $post->user->name
```

Have a good day

Comment: That's right, but I would have to do that whenever I try to access the user data.